# Can you say "voilà pour" before as well as after offering an explanation?

Tags: usage

> **Voilà pour** la présentation de ...
>
> **Voilà pour** la base !

I usually use  "voilà pour ..." just ***after*** I have completed an explanation of something, but I wonder if you can also use it just ***before*** offering an explanation?

Comment: If I may, I rarely hear _voici_ in speaken langage. However, you can almost always switch it with _voilà_ anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, "*voilà pour*" is generally used in **speech** to conclude (after an action, an explanation or a listing):

> **Voilà pour** aujourd'hui ! (*C'est tout pour aujourd'hui !*)

You could insert a noun in between to introduce the subject before the explanation:

> **Voilà** les instructions **pour** monter le meuble : ...

However it sounds "poor" to me when written, I would use another form of wording:

> Les instructions de montage du meuble sont les suivantes : ...

Answer (score 1):

***Voici** la présentation...* sounds right. Besides, the difference between *voici* and *voilà* is slight in the day-to-day usage, so you could as well say ***voilà** la présentation*.

You would say *voici **pour*** when giving somebody something (*voici pour toi* means *here for you*).

Answer (score 1):

*Voilà* placé avant le commencement de quelque chose est principalement pour désigner quelque chose que vous pouvez voir ou sentir, dans le sens d'une présentation, je ne pense pas que ce soit très adapté.

> **Voilà** mon ami qui arrive
>
> **Voilà** la maison, elle est belle, n'est-ce pas ?

*Voilà* est également utilisé après une explication comme vous l'avez déjà illustré dans votre exemple

> **Voilà**, c'est terminé !

*Voici* est plus commun pour introduire quelque chose et donc serait plus adapté à cette situation.

> **Voici** la présentation de

*Voici* n'est cependant pas très utilisé dans le français parlé, c'est donc préférable de n'utiliser ni *voici* ni *voilà* dans ce cas. Vous pouvez le remplacer par exemple par le verbe `commencer` dans votre cas.

> **Commençons** la présentation...

Answer (score 1):

"Voilà pour", used after, sounds right when you use it with a conclusive intonation (falling intonation) that is implying "and I won't say anything else about this subject". For that reason, using it with that kind of intonation before the explanation may sound a bit strange.

However, if you say it with an announciating tone implying "I'm about to tell you about it" (rising intonation), it may sound ok. Semantically at least, it is correct to say it before.

I also find "Voilà pour [...] :" a bit weak if said before, however. I would recommend emphasizing the fact you are transitioning to the explanation by adding *alors*: "Alors, voilà pour la présentation : [...]".

In conclusion, "Voilà pour", used before the explanation, is intended to be used as a transitioning tool (as opposite to when used after where it is a conclusive tool): there must be one subject introduced before you use "Voilà pour", and the explanation of that subject after you use "Voilà pour".

Answer (score 1):

You can't use "Voilà pour" before offering an explanation. It's because of "pour", which refers what you've explained before. As if, in english, you start a sentence by "Those are…" without any previous indication of a reference.

There are some specific cases of use but somehow it's always related to something that happened before, and all the participants know it.
E.g.:

> Voilà pour toi.

It's used when giving something to a receiver who known he was about to get something. He was prepared to receive. And "voilà pour toi" is more a saying of "now let's do it".